# Дублирование действий главного ПК на другие, подключенные к нему

Tags: python

Возник запрос, на создание софта, для "автоследования".

Мне нужен софт, который бы один в один передавал действия от главного пк на другие, n-кол-во. Т.е. подключил к главному ПК ещё 3. По soket или IP. На главном ПК открыл браузер, на 3х других тоже открылись драузеры, Главный ПК перешёл на главную страницу google, 3 других сделали тоже самое, и т.д.
И всё это с минимальной задержкой 1-0,1 сек. Понято, что тут ещё зависит от интернета всё, но всё же.

В каком направлении копать, какие-то статьи?

Comment: Интересный вопрос, но мне кажется, что при любой имплементации задержка будет больше чем вы ожидаете. Все таки графический интерфейс. Даже если просто будут отсылаться команды на параллельные машины, не будет гарантий, что страница будет загружаться с одинаковой скоростью.

Comment: Непонятен смысл. Чем вам простая трансляция экрана, например, не подходит?

Comment: @Kromster на сколько я понял эти разные машины исполняют команды параллельно, но каждая работает по своему. Трансляция экрана скорей всего не то, о чем думает ТС. Но тут уж он сам должен пояснить свои мотивы и цель

Comment: "Действия" - очень расплывчатое понятие. Наверное, как-то можно передавать события мыши и клавиатуры, но тут никакой синхронности получить не удасться. Например, на ведомом компьютере браузер открывался на долю секунды дольше, страница открывалась на долю секунду дольше - и какие-то события мыши/клавиатуры сделают совсем не то, что вы хотели. И после этого расхождения на ведущем и ведомом компьютерах будут нарастать уже лавинообразно.

Comment: ^ не считая разницы в разрешениях экрана, того как открывается прога - на фулскрин или нет., любви виндов передавать фокус по каким-то событиям и тп

Comment: В общем, для начала нужно начать с описания задачи не в терминах того, как это должно выглядеть для пользователя, а в терминах компьютера - то есть на языке системных событий, протоколов, и т.п. Но, кажется, что в любом случае задача будет очень сложная, мутная, и явно не для питона.

Answer (score 0):

Суть программы - мультиаккаунт. Выполняя однотипные действия, дублируя их на несколько ПК. Например: покупка крипты, участие в лаунчпадах. Когда меняется только аккаунт, а действия те же.

Трансляция не подходит, т.к. на другом ПК, должны выполняться те же действия автоматически.

Разницей в разрешениях экранов вопрос решается )))

Насчёт задержки, открытия страниц, скорость интерента, скорость загрузки - да, много переменных, которые влиют на итогый результат, и с которыми придётся по потеть, согласен.

Насчёт загружки есть конечно мысли, решал это обычной паузой, при загрузках страниц. Возможно, потестировав, 1-2 секунды задержки будут не критичны. Как в телетрансляциях. Это покажут только тесты.

Итого: спасибо за комментарии друзья. Понял с чего начать, и как делать подобную прогу)) Остался вопрос только - цена? Сколько это может стоить?
И вообще, было бы интересно, кто как оценивает проекты? От чего отталкиватесь при ценообразовании?

А насчёт - задача явно не для питона - Почему?
Ведь хватает примеро, когда целые сервисы реализованы на python. А тут небольшая прога ))

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).